# ORA-02270 although there's primary key

Tags: oracle, primary-key

Given this schema:

```
create table Review2 (
RID varchar(3),
YID varchar(3),
BID varchar(3),
-- other columns
primary key(RID,YID,BID)
);

create table textualContent2(
TID varchar(3),
RID varchar(3) NOT NULL,
-- other columns
primary key (TID),
foreign key (RID) references Review2 on delete cascade
);
```

I get this error:

> ORA-02256: number of referencing columns must match referenced columns

Why is that and how do I fix it?

Comment: Post the actual question here, not a link to who-knows-what.

Comment: I have edited my post. It was a picture. Can you help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: In the question title you reference one error message: ORA-02270. But your actual question shows a different error: ORA-02256. What happened? Did you realize that you did not, in fact, have a PK (contrary to what you said), you then added it, and ran into a different error? In any case, the error message is pretty clear. You can't have a composite PK in the first table (on three columns), and then have a FK in the other table on only one column, referencing one of the three columns in the PK on the first table. What is there that you don't understand?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. What should I do if I only need to reference one of the three columns in the PK on the first table? If I reference all three column, I would have to have the other column as a column in the second table too, right?

Comment: thats right. A primary key is a single "thing". Whether it is made from 1 column or 10 columns, they constitute a single key. Thus that key (whether it be 1 column or 2 or 10) is what is needed for all tables involved in a FK back to the parent.

Comment: A foreign key doesn't necessarily reference a primary key but any key. So if `rid` in `review2` is logically unique, you can define a unique constraint on it that the foreign key can reference.

Answer (score 0):

Review2 has PK:

```
primary key(RID,YID,BID),
```

but your FK definition

```
foreign key (RID) references Review2
```

uses the shorthand version, which implies referenced columns as being the PK columns `(RID,YID,BID)`, so it's the same as coding:

```
foreign key (RID) references Review2(RID,YID,BID)
```

As suggested by the error message:

> number of referencing columns must match referenced columns

the number of columns referenced `(RID,YID,BID)` disagrees those referencing `(RID)`.

To fix the problem, either change your FK to:

```
foreign key (RID) references Review2(RID)
```

and define a unique constraint on `RID` in `Review2`, or add columns `YID` and `BID` to `textualContent2` and add them to the FK:

```
foreign key (RID,YID,BID) references Review2(RID,YID,BID)
```

Comment: YW. See [What to do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).